# Which columns should I create Index?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite 3. I have a table MyTable, as follows:

```
    Create table mytable (a as INTEGER, b as INTEGER, c as INTGER, c as INTEGER);

    Insert into mytable (a,b,c,d) values (1, 1,1,1);
    Insert into mytable (a,b,c,d) values (1, 2,1,2);
    Insert into mytable (a,b,c,d) values (2, 1,1,3);
    Insert into mytable (a,b,c,d) values (2, 3,2,1);
    Insert into mytable (a,b,c,d) values (3, 1,2,3);
```

After adding data, I need to perform the following query frequently:

```
    Select * from mytable where (a = ##) and (b = ##) and (c = ##) and (d < ##);
```

In such a case, which columns should be used to create the index before performing the query?

I am thinking of using

```
    Create Index MyIndex on mytable (a, b, c, d);
```

That is, creating index for all a, b, c, d columns. Is that correct?

Comment: why not create a seperrate table for a,b,c and have the primary key of table abc on mytable as foreign key, and create index just for that .

Comment: Some helpful reading for how sqlite uses indexes: https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html (But yes, that looks good as long as you're okay with doubling the space taken by the table. If every particular `(a,b,c,d)` is unique, consider making that the primary key in a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the best index for your query.  The columns `a`, `b`, and `c` can be in any order, but `d` needs to follow them.

Comment: Thank yo u very much.